# Installing Tibco EMS transport channel for WCF

Tags: wcf, tibco, tibco-ems

Can anyone please let me know where I can get the "Tibco EMS Transport Channel for WCF". I know this is not a technical question. But I couldn't find any information online. I found the documentation on how to install it but not where to download it from.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friend [eDelivery](https://edelivery.tibco.com/storefront/index.ep).

Obviously, you need an account @ TIBCO. Talk to your salesmen.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response. I think, since I have only evaluation account, I don't see the options to choose 'Individual file download'. Anyways, once again, thanks for the answer. Now, atleast I know :)

Comment: Make sure you let your local sales team know... they will be eager to help ;-)